# Typescript typecheck extended class

Tags: typescript, angular

I need to pass a reference around to a class that is extended from another class. This is because I have an Angular 2 modal service that will dynamically instantiate a component when given.

The modal service does this based on modal options it is passed. One of these options is a component. I need this component to extend to ensure that the component passed has certain methods on it that can be called.

My modal options class is very simple as follows:

```
export class ModalOptions {
    constructor(
        public component: typeof ModalClass,
        public title: string,
        public size: string = "med"
    ) { }
}
```

ModalClass is a very simple class:

```
export class ModalClass {
    public ok(): Promise<void> {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    public cancel(): Promise<void> {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

So if I extend this class as a component like so:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    templateUrl: "...",
})
export class MyComponent extends ModalClass {
    public details: SomeType;

    constructor(
        // Stuff
    ) {
        super();
        this.details = //Stuff
    }

}
```

I want to be able to build a modal options object with it and pass that around. I want to be able to typecheck the component given in ModalOptions to ensure it fits the criteria.

However, while this works in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20NewGreeter%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(message)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%22hello%20you%20person%20you%3A%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%20%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20options%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(%0D%0A%09%09public%20greeter%3A%20typeof%20Greeter%0D%0A%09)%20%7B%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myOptions%20%3D%20new%20options(NewGreeter)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20Greeter)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20NewGreeter)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20Greeter%20%3D%3D%3D%20typeof%20NewGreeter)%3B), Typescript in Visual Studio does not like it at all and won't compile.

`"Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof ModalClass'."`

I have typescript compiler version 1.8.10.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: What happens if you remove the 'typeof' operator?

Comment: It throws an error because I'm passing in a type instead of an actual class.