# Typescript reference extended class

Tags: typescript, class

I need to reference a class which extends my base class and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out. I'm unsure how to explain it, so I made a demonstration code:

```
interface BaseAttributes {
    id: string;
}

interface Relation {
    field: string;
    class: typeof One;
}

    class One<A extends BaseAttributes> {
    private relations: Relation[];
    private attr: A;

    constructor(attr: A) {
        this.attr = attr;

        this.relations = (this.constructor as typeof One).getRelations();
    }

    static getRelations(): Relation[] {
        return [];
    }

    static getOne() {
        // Some data fetching here
        const data: TwoAttributes = {
            id: '123',
            label: 'test',
        };

        return new this(data);
    }

    doRelations() {
        return this.relations.map((relation: Relation) => {
            return relation.class.getOne();
        });
    }
}

interface TwoAttributes extends BaseAttributes{
    label: string;
}

class Two extends One<TwoAttributes> {
    static getRelations(): Relation[] {
        return [
            {
                field: 'test',
                class: Three,
            },
        ];
    }
}

interface ThreeAttributes extends BaseAttributes{
    image: string;
}

class Three extends One<ThreeAttributes> {
}
```

Basically 'One' is a class, which has some attributes and relations. Those relations can refer to other 'One' classes or classes which extend it. Problem is, in the class 'Two' - implementation of getRelations - I get

```
Type '{ field: string; class: typeof Three; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Relation[]'.
  Type '{ field: string; class: typeof Three; }' is not assignable to type 'Relation'.
    Types of property 'class' are incompatible.
      Type 'typeof Three' is not assignable to type 'typeof One'.
        Types of parameters 'attr' and 'attr' are incompatible.
          Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'ThreeAttributes'.
            Type 'BaseAttributes' is not assignable to type 'ThreeAttributes'.
              Property 'image' is missing in type 'BaseAttributes'.
```

I tried messing around with different variations of using 'typeof' and not using it, but in the Relation I need it in order to reference the class itself.

I've also been able to find SO question with same problem, but it was never answered. [Link to the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487156/typescript-typecheck-extended-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value `One` is a constructor for a generic class, its type, `typeof One` is something like:

```
type TypeofOne = {
    new <A extends BaseAttributes>(attr: A): One<A>;
    getRelations(): Relation[];
}
```

(You can verify that these are essentially the same type by noting that the following code has no errors:

```
type Same<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = true;
declare const checkTypeofOne: Same<typeof One, TypeofOne>;
```

In this case, `typeof One` and `TypeofOne` are seen by the compiler to mutually extend each other... which is close to being "the same type".)

Anyway, that signature means that `typeof one` is a constructor that takes a parameter of a generic type `A` and returns a `One<A>`.  But `Three` does *not* do that.  It only accepts a parameter of type `ThreeAttributes`, and produces a `One<ThreeAttributes>`.  So you cannot pass in `Three` where you're expecting a `TypeofOne`.

So maybe you don't really want the `class` property of a `Relation` to be restricted to `TypeofOne`.

---

Perhaps you *really* want to say something like: "the `class` property of a `Relation` can be any constructor that produces some instance of `One<A>` for some `A`".  Technically that would require [existential types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) to properly encode, and [TypeScript doesn't have those](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  But maybe you'd be okay with: "the `class` property of a `Relation` is a constructor that produces a `One<any>`".  Something like:

```
type TypeofAnyOne = {
    new(attr: any): One<any>;
    getRelations(): Relation[];
}
```

In this case you can see that `TypeofAnyOne` is not necessarily a generic constructor.  It will match a constructor which takes `any` parameter and produces a `One<any>`. Caveat: whenever you use [the any type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) you aren't being completely type safe... in this case it's possible for `TypeofAnyOne` to match a constructor that accepts a `string` and produces a `One<number>`, which shouldn't even be possible since neither `string` nor `number` match `BaseAttributes`.

So if you change `Relation['class']` to be `TypeofAnyOne` instead of `TypeofOne` it will work without errors:

```
interface Relation {
    field: string;
    class: TypeofAnyOne; // okay now
}
```

That might be good enough for you, depending what you're trying to actually do with your `Relation` array.  In any case, hope that helps point you in a useful direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer! I've updated the `One` class to show what I actually do. Based on some condition I call a static method of the `class` on `Relation`, this static method will always be defined on the `One` class, so your recommended approach should be enough. I don't really like it, as it causes sort of a code duplication, but if it's the only way I'll use it.
I'm marking your answer as accepted, as it clarifies the problem and provides a solution but please let me know if it can be somehow beatified.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to represent `TypeofAnyOne` in terms of `typeof One`.  Maybe make a non-generic `Zero` class which behaves like `One<any>`, and then make `One<A>` a subclass of it?  then `typeof Zero` would be similar to `TypeofAnyOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the accepted answer provides a solution, I was able to resolve it with a different approach which gets rid of the code duplication, but introduces a different ugly thing.

Instead of using

```
static getRelations(): Relation[] {
    return [
        {
            field: 'test',
            class: Three,
        },
    ];
}
```

I was able to get it working like this:

```
static getRelations(): Relation[] {
    return [
        {
            field: 'test',
            class: Three as typeof One,
        },
    ];
}
```

This is nice because it allows me to use

```
interface Relation {
    field: string;
    class: typeof One;
}
```

and still get all the methods `One` defines. The `as` still causes a weird code, especially if there are more relations, but over all I like it more.